# How to launch Universal Windows app from another Universal Windows app installed in the same system?

Tags: javascript, uwp

My requirement is to launch an Universal Windows app on button click performed in another Universal Windows app,
My application is developed in javascript.

Example which does not work,
Its working fine in Windows 10 desktop but not working on Windows IOT os:

```
$(document).on('click', '.openDPPA', function () {
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = 1;
    try {
        var testAppUri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri("test2-app2app:");
        var n = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
        options.TargetApplicationPackageFamilyName = "DPPAApp_ehke6zp0mbebr";
    }

    catch (err) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = err.message;
    }
    Windows.System.Launcher.launchUriAsync(testAppUri, options).then(
        function (success) {
            if (success) {
                // URI launched
                x = "success";
                $("#errorLabel").html("success");
            } else {
                x = "failed";
                $("#errorLabel").html("failed");
                // URI launch failed
            }
        });

});
```

Try caught showing error message as

> Unable to get property then of undefined or null reference.

Comment: Do you control the app you're trying to launch? Easiest solution is probably to register a custom scheme ("protocol") for the app and launch it via `Launcer.launchUriAysnc()`

Comment: Peter did u know any documentation for that same.

Comment: Please refer [Handle URI activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation).

Comment: Thank you Peter and Nico i made it.but i am facing another issue if possible kindly replay https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51631652/launch-uwp-app-from-another-uwp-app-not-happening-with-windows-factory-os

Comment: In this case I think the problem of the error is that you call the `LauncherOptions` `n` in the first line, but `options` on the second line

Comment: Also the `launchUriAsync` call must be inside the `try` block, otherwise `options` will be out of scope by then

Comment: I tried the same sir but it showing same error(code updated)

Answer (score 0):

The following code works in Windows IoT Core

```
$(document).on('click', '.openDPPA', function () {
       try {
            var testAppUri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri("test2-app2app:");
            var n = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
            options.TargetApplicationPackageFamilyName = "DPPAApp_ehke6zp0mbebr";
            options.treatedAsUntrusted = false;
        }

        catch (err) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = err.message;
        }
        Windows.System.Launcher.launchUriAsync(testAppUri, options).then(
            function (success) {
                if (success) {
                    // URI launched

                } else {

                    // URI launch failed
                }
            });

    });
```