# How to launch javascript universal windows application from another UWP app in windows IoT?

Tags: javascript, windows, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-iot-core

My requirement is to launch UWP app from another UWP app.And i made it but its working in windows 10 desktop system not on Windows IoT OS,Kindly help me to fix this.

```
$(document).on('click', '.openTAT', function () {
    var testAppUri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri("test-app2app:");
    var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
    options.TargetApplicationPackageFamilyName = "TATApp_ehke6zp0mbebr";
    Windows.System.Launcher.launchUriAsync(testAppUri, options).then(
        function (success) {
            if (success) {
                // URI launched
                x = "success";
                $("#errorLabel").html("success");
            } else {
                x = "failed";
                $("#errorLabel").html("failed");
                // URI launch failed
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: What happens if you don't specify the `TargetApplicationPackageFamilyName`?

Comment: I have tested this issue on my Windows IoT Core, but with used different `click` method. The TATApp could be launched. Are you sure the click method is triggered on your Factory OS?@Lokesh Raj

Comment: In addition, what is the Windows Factory OS in you question? Is it Windows IoT Core? Can you launch the TATApp manually on your Factory OS?

Comment: Factory os is advanced form of Windows IoT Platform

Comment: different click mentord,can you please explain the same

Comment: Click method is triggering but after that its crashing

Comment: @LokeshRaj,  is the Factory os a third-party customized os ? We could get windows iot core and windows iot enterpise. In addition as Martin Zikmund mentioned, did you test with removing the `TargetApplicationPackageFamilyName`? And normally, it is necessary to add the default active page in the url, such as `test-app2app:MainPage`.